# Display warning when NumberPicker number exceed Max on Keyboard Entry

Tags: android, android-edittext, numberpicker

I have a Number Picker that allow user to enter some number within a fixed range.

By default the number will not allow the user to enter a number larger than the max set for the number picker.

However i would like to display a message when that happens. Is there a way to access the edittext in the number picker ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement TextChangedListener that will register every change in the field so that you can act accordingly on it.

for example.

```
 yourEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.yourEditTextId);

    yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

      public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        // you can call or do what you want with your EditText here
        yourEditText. ... 

      }

      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
   });
```